# An algorithm to extract the purpose of a document

Tags: nlp, lstm, bert, transformer, attention-mechanism

I want to build an algorithm to extract the **purpose of the document** (scientific papers for example) by extracting the sentences that state the purpose. I don't have many annotated data so I might use a semi-supervised learning algorithm. I was thinking of training a Q/A algorithm (using Bert for example..) but I want something to be specific to the purpose task..

Any idea or keywords that might help ?
Thanks!

Comment: if you have a fixed set of classes for "purpose of the document", then you might think of "intent classification" based approach used in Chatbots.

Comment: Thanks! I think that'll be helpful :)

Comment: I looked it up and it's quite interesting. The only problem is that the intent classification (& slot filling) is a supervised approach (training data with corresponding labels of intent classes) but I'll see if I can get around with a semi-supervised way

Comment: Yes, you might try pseudo labeling approach!!

Comment: Another approach would be text summarization. In the case of scientific articles just extracting the abstract should be sufficient, since it's supposed to describe the purpose of the paper.

Comment: @Erwan yes I've tried text summarization (based on TextRank of gensim). It does give some good results but not always..

Comment: @DevashishPrasad I'll look it up. Thanks!